# ffmpeg convert any file to any file

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, command

I Want simple command to convert any supported file to any file with little possible video compression.

for example

```
avi to mp4
mp4 to 3gp
.
.etc..
```

I tried below code

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flv outfile.3gp
```

It works for some but for some other like `flv to 3gp` conversion it throws error like below and also output file size is very large than input.

```
"Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"
```

P:s  i compiled with below librareis

```
./configure --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree
```

full response

```
array(48) {
  [0]=>
  string(77) "ffmpeg version N-72286-gd9b264b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers"
  [1]=>
  string(56) "  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)"
  [2]=>
  string(261) "  configuration: --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree"
  [3]=>
  string(40) "  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101"
  [4]=>
  string(40) "  libavcodec     56. 39.101 / 56. 39.101"
  [5]=>
  string(40) "  libavformat    56. 33.101 / 56. 33.101"
  [6]=>
  string(40) "  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100"
  [7]=>
  string(40) "  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101"
  [8]=>
  string(40) "  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101"
  [9]=>
  string(40) "  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100"
  [10]=>
  string(40) "  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100"
  [11]=>
  string(32) "Input #0, flv, from 'video.flv':"
  [12]=>
  string(11) "  Metadata:"
  [13]=>
  string(25) "    major_brand     : M4V"
  [14]=>
  string(23) "    minor_version   : 1"
  [15]=>
  string(39) "    compatible_brands: M4V M4A mp42isom"
  [16]=>
  string(26) "    date            : 2008"
  [17]=>
  string(71) "    copyright       : © 2008 Blender Foundation | www.bigbuckbunny.org"
  [18]=>
  string(36) "    title           : Big Buck Bunny"
  [19]=>
  string(43) "    artist          : Peach Open Movie Team"
  [20]=>
  string(56) "    composer        : Sacha Goedegebure / Ton Roosendaal"
  [21]=>
  string(35) "    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100"
  [22]=>
  string(59) "  Duration: 00:09:56.58, start: 0.058000, bitrate: 663 kb/s"
  [23]=>
  string(88) "    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 640x360, 24.42 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc"
  [24]=>
  string(61) "    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s"
  [25]=>
  string(90) "[h263 @ 0x1ef5f60] The specified picture size of 640x360 is not valid for the H.263 codec."
  [26]=>
  string(77) "Valid sizes are 128x96, 176x144, 352x288, 704x576, and 1408x1152. Try H.263+."
  [27]=>
  string(33) "Output #0, 3gp, to 'outfile.3gp':"
  [28]=>
  string(11) "  Metadata:"
  [29]=>
  string(25) "    major_brand     : M4V"
  [30]=>
  string(23) "    minor_version   : 1"
  [31]=>
  string(39) "    compatible_brands: M4V M4A mp42isom"
  [32]=>
  string(26) "    date            : 2008"
  [33]=>
  string(71) "    copyright       : © 2008 Blender Foundation | www.bigbuckbunny.org"
  [34]=>
  string(36) "    title           : Big Buck Bunny"
  [35]=>
  string(43) "    artist          : Peach Open Movie Team"
  [36]=>
  string(56) "    composer        : Sacha Goedegebure / Ton Roosendaal"
  [37]=>
  string(35) "    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100"
  [38]=>
  string(60) "    Stream #0:0: Video: h263, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 24 fps"
  [39]=>
  string(13) "    Metadata:"
  [40]=>
  string(42) "      encoder         : Lavc56.39.101 h263"
  [41]=>
  string(52) "    Stream #0:1: Audio: amr_nb, 0 channels, 128 kb/s"
  [42]=>
  string(13) "    Metadata:"
  [43]=>
  string(55) "      encoder         : Lavc56.39.101 libopencore_amrnb"
  [44]=>
  string(15) "Stream mapping:"
  [45]=>
  string(54) "  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h263 (native))"
  [46]=>
  string(66) "  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> amr_nb (libopencore_amrnb))"
  [47]=>
  string(119) "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"
}
```

Comment: It would help if you listed the complete ffmpeg log of a failing case.

Comment: I see ? why there is lots of other ffmpeg question and why ffmpeg tag even exist ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [3gp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GP_and_3G2) is a flexible container format, you have to give `ffmpeg` some parameters as *video bitrate, frame size, video codec, audio bitrate, audio codec*.

For example, the following code extracted from a [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1254647):

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -b 300k -s 320x240 -vcodec mpeg4 -ac 2 -ab 128k -acodec libfaac output.3gp
```

Comment: only 3gp is like this or any other video format requires something like this ?

Comment: As stated [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg):
 `By default, FFmpeg tries to convert as losslessly as possible: It uses the same audio and video parameters for the outputs as the one specified for the inputs.`
 So it is better to explicitly pass those main parameters and have control over your output rather than letting ffmpeg try to convert losslessly and fail.

Comment: but I cant pass 320x240 for all video !!

Comment: That's an example, you can pass any size that you want but for 3gp which is a mobile oriented format you need to pass small values. Try setting the size only on 3gp conversions and formats that fail with similar output: `[...]maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"`

Comment: The video options in the example are: `-b bitrate` (Set the video bitrate in bit/s) `-s size` (Set frame size. The format is WidthxHeight) `-vcodec codec` (Force video codec to codec)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing between the issues of *format* and *encoding*. `.3gp` and `.flv` are just container formats, the fact that a file contains media in this format doesn't tell us much about the media encoding. ffmpeg can figure the input encoding, but has no clue how you want to encode the outfile. What you look for is this:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flv -strict -2 -c:v h264 -c:a aac outfile.3gp
```

The above line tells ffmpeg to encode the video as h.264 and the audio as aac, and then pack it into a `.3gp` container.

Answer (score -1):

It's seems to be a problem  with your ff mpeg package. Try to install it from your package manager.

**alternatively** use  any of the gui front end of ffmpeg like **mobile media converter**. mmc contains stable version of well working ffmpeg.